# pdo_odbc query returns too few parameters 1 expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to test codeigniter with a pdo_odbc driver to connect to an ms accdb database, connection works the matter is when I'm trying to querying it with a simple `select * from ACHATS where N°Achat=31` without where clause it works.
the error returned is :

```
Error Number: 07002/-3010

[Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Trop peu de param�tres. 1 attendu. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)

select * from ACHATS where N°Achat=31

Filename: D:/Dev/wamp/www/agendaOuestPalettes/system/database/DB_driver.php
```

I'm not used to MS Access and a little bit confused to fail with a super simple query...
Thanks for your help.

[Edit]
My model function is as simple as this :

```
`public function find($value) {

    $this->load->database();

    $this->output->set_output($value);

    //die($value);

    //$q = $this->db->get_where("ACHATS", array("N°Achat" => "'31'"));
    /*$q = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('ACHATS')
            ->where('N°Achat', '31')
            ->get();*/

    $array_pdo_query = array($value);
    //die(var_dump($array_pdo_query));

    $q = $this->db->query('select * from ACHATS where N°Achat=?', $array_pdo_query);

    $r = $q->result(get_class($this));

    return $r;

}`
```

Comment: What happens if you change `N°Achat` to `[N°Achat]`?

Comment: Nothing same error with [N°Achat] in addition I've tried with quotes, simple or double nothing !

Comment: Try just `select * from ACHATS`, and see if that works.

Comment: yes as I said before without where clause it works .

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but thought you need methods such as `prepare` and `bind_param` for a parameter query.  Are those not required?

Comment: You might need the CHR code for the degree symbol perhaps? Try changing where clause to WHERE N  &  CHR(0176) & Achate=?

Comment: I don't think it's the problem because `select * from ACHATS` works fine, I suspect more that ms-access need simple quotes after where like that `select * from ACHATS where N°Achat = '31'` which are escaped by pdo

Comment: I've tried with CHR(0176) fail...

Comment: the generated query `select * from ACHATS where N°Achat=31;  ` is running perfect for netbeans idon't understand what's the problem for php_odbc ?

Comment: I'm able to create a table called `ACHATS` with a column `N°Achat` and run the query `select * from ACHATS where N°Achat=31;` from Access so that looks good. But I agree with HansUp, I don't see where you are populating your parameters for your query. How does `?` get filled in?

Comment: thanks for your help, simply my controller call the find method with the parameter 31 like that  `$data['achatTest'] = $this->AchatModel->find(31);` . I agree from access it works, not from php with pdo_odbc.

Comment: Anyone have an idea ? I see that when I give `'31'` to my find method pdo escape single quotes and I've seen on some related topics that pdo_odbc needs single quotes to work, so what can I do ?